# Does backing up an Azure database take it down at all?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a database in Azure and I am backing it up using

```
   az sql db export  .....
```

I need to know does that at all take the database down , affect any running transactions or take it temporarily offline ?

Is there any documentation that explain this?

Comment: What kind of database? Cosmos DB SQL?

Comment: No it is a Azure SQL Managed Instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/unexpected-select-queries-seen-in-the-performance-overview-of/ba-p/368807), and export may produce unexpected spikes of DTU consumption in the performance graphs on the Azure Portal even during times of low database activity. So the exports do affect the performance.

Comment: So performance is affected , but its not taken offline. I guess it will bounce back to optimal performance once it is backed up ?

Comment: One export generates a sudden spike when the operation is initiated after that you don't see more spikes while the export is in progress.

Comment: Im a bit confused here. Earlier you mentioned it causes spikes in DTU and now only on initiation. So is it a good idea to use this to make a full backup or can i use the az sql db replica create... ? what is the difference between the 2 cmds ? Dont they produce the same result, a bacpac file of full backup ?

Comment: "az sql db replica create" is for creating replicas for Geo-replication. Meanwhile "az sql db export" creates a backup (a bacpac) of an Azure SQL database. On each use of sqlpackage or any exporrt initiated you will see they create an spike when they initiate only and not during the whole process. Reading my answer to your question I do not seem to read where I said there will be many spikes on each export. You can try it yourself.

Comment: So will a replicate produce a full backup , similar to fullbackup whereby it copies everything, users , permission etc ?

Comment: when i do the az sq db export ... i get an error , Message: The ImportExport operation  failed due to 'An error occurred while communicating with the SQL Server using AdPassword-login: Could not discover a user realm.', any ideas on this ?

Comment: i am using :     
az sql db export -s pds1 -n pdb1 -g resourcegroup --admin-password "password" --admin-user "username" --auth-type ADPassword --storage-key accesskey== --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri "https://storage accname.blob.core.windows.net/folder1/myBacpac.bacpac"

Comment: About the error you received while importing/exporting please create a new question so the question and it related answers can be indexed by Search Engines and others can benefit from that. I have already answered to the best of my possibilities your original question. Thank you for your undestanding